# Bulk export all Libraries using IBM I series

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I don't have permission for AS400 Server. I can export data using "Data Transfer from iSeries". I can't able to bulk export files. I can able to export only file to excel format. IS there any way to bulk export of all files in library.

I have 126 library with 10k files.

I want to export all library file to .Csv files.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

**Finally i got Solution. Posted my solution in this question**

Comment: You would need server access to write a script that would bundle all the files into a folder in CSV format. PHP would work very well. A PHP script would use SQL to read all the tables in a schema, copy the contents to CSV, then even zip the output and download to the browser.

Comment: @StephenRichter, thank you. but My bad luck i dont know about PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can't not have permission to an IBM i server, yet be able to transfer data.

There is no built in way to export data from every file in a library.  You'll need to create a program that retrieves a list of files, then export each individually.

From the server side, you could do this in CL and with the CPYTOIMPF command.

From the PC side, you can use C#, Java, or basically anything that supports an ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

We can able to export As400 all libraries to Sql server using

1)SSIS Package
2)Linked server
3)Sql server Import Export Wizard.

Sql server is installed and ODBC installed for AS400 in my iseries navigator server.
Hence i created Linked server for my AS400 server using "**IBM DB2 for i IBMDQSQL OLE DB Provider"**

Create Linked server:

Linked server Name: Give name for Linked server
Server type: Other data source
Provider: IBM DB2 for i IBMDQSQL OLE DB Provider
Data Source: AS400 server ip address
Security : Click radio button for Be made using this security context
REmote login: Give id to access as400 server
with password: Give password of to access the as400 server

Click ok.

Now linked server is created. we can see the database name of AS400. but we cant able to see the libraries. we can get the information of libararies using query.

If need more information. Comment it. I will Help you.